# Python create variable according to for loop index

Tags: python, variables, for-loop

I am trying to create variable for each iteration of the for loop:

for i in range(10):
x(i) = 'abc'

so that I would get x1, x2, x3, x4, .... x10, all equal to 'abc'

Anyone know how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about `list`s in Python?

Comment: This question has been asked many times before, do not use `eval`, `locals` and such - use a dictionary to map key to value: `{'x1': 'abc', 'x2': 'xyz', ...}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be doing that, store your values in a `dict` if you want to access them by name, or a `list` if you want to access them by index, but if you really insist:

```
for i in range(10):
    locals()["x" + str(i)] = "abc"  # use globals() to store the vars in the global stack

print(x3)  # abc
```

Comment: One unlikely situation where such automated variable creation is needed is a call from python to TabPy (Tableau Python Server) via the `query()` function from `tabpy` package. The use of variable-length collection of parameters here is due to Tableau constraints (no multi-column data formats)

Comment: Hello, I agree with you about using a dict instead of creating variables inside the for loop, however if I need to store diferent values per iteration in the same name of the dict, it can't be done, or maybe I still don't know how to do it. Thank for your answer and if you have some insight about it, it would be awasome.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the easiest way for beginners. You might want to learn how to use lists:

```
>>> x = []
>>> for i in range(10):
    x.append('abc')

>>> print(x[0])
abc
>>> print(x[8])
abc
>>> print(x)
['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'abc']
```

You can also use [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) or locals:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
    globals()["x" + str(i)] = 'abc'
>>> x1
'abc'
```

Useful links:

1. [Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)